# Scroll block with page in drupal

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-blocks

Is it possible that if i scroll down on drupal the block should also scroll along with the page. Because i have to display long results on the node and i want to scroll the block so that user can see the data on left sidebar everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need it to be animated, you can simply use the "position: fixed" CSS attribute.

Assuming your block is 10px from the left, and 50px from the top it would look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="scrolling-block">
    I can see you!
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.scrolling-block {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Also, check this out.
http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/fixed.html